# How to close modals?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got 3 modals and all 3 of them open great, but they will not close when you click outside the modal or even click on the X at the top-right of the modal.

I have searched on here, youtube ect and even reserched about modals, but I am unable to find a solution to the problem.

HTML

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="subscribe" id="subscribe">Subscribe</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="subscription" class="subscribe-modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="subscribe-content">
    <div class="subscribe-header">
      <span class="close"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="subscribe-body">
      <h2>Subscribe to the Galaxy Mailing List</h2>
      <p>Welcome to the Galaxy Games Subscription Management page. Galaxy mailing lists are the best way to get the early word on all our game announcements, official launches, contests, special events, and more. Make sure you're enlisted to receive all
        the updates.</p>
        <a href="https://socialclub.galaxy-games.co.uk/settings/email" class="manage" target="_blank" click="closeSection()" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Club" data-gtm-label="Manage Subscription Account">Manage Your Account</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
                <li><a href="http://support.galaxy-games.co.uk/" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Support">Support</a></li>

                <li><a href="/careers" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Careers">Careers</a></li>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="mouthoff" id="mouthoff">mouthoff</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="shout" class="mouthoff-modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="mouthoff-content">
    <div class="mouthoff-header">
      <span class="close"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="mouthoff-body">
      <h2>Mouthoff - Tell Us What's On Your Mind</h2>
      <p>Have something you want to tell us, ask us or bring to our attention? Feel free to Mouthoff and let us know here. Please bear in mind that we may not be able to answer absolutely everything and we won’t reveal to you any game info that hasn't yet been announced, but we’re always happy to have a look at what you have to say.</p><p>If you have a technical issue that you’d like to report, please <a href="http://www.galaxy-games.co.uk/support" target="_blank">contact our Support Team</a>.</p>
        <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="row common-form pristine valid" action="https://www.galaxy-games.co.uk/mouthoff/mouthoff/submit.json">
                            <div style="display:none;">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" autocomplete="off"></div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-5 col-xxs-12">
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" maxlength="100" placeholder="Name" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide your name')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required="required" id="name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-5 col-xxs-12">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email Address" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide your email address')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required="required" id="email" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xxs-12">
                                    <label for="age">Age</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="age" class="form-control" min="13" max="100" pattern="[0-9]{2}" placeholder="Age" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide your age')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required="required" id="age">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-xxs-12">
                                    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" maxlength="100" placeholder="Subject" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide a subject')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required="required" id="subject">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xxs-12">
                                    <select name="category_id" required="required" id="category-id">
                                        <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                        <option value="1">General Suggestions</option>
                                        <option value="2">GTA Online Suggestions</option>
                                        <option value="3">Crews</option>
                                        <option value="4">Other Social Club Features</option>
                                        <option value="5">Galaxy Warehouse</option>
                                        <option value="6">Customer Support</option>
                                        <option value="7">Other Feedback</option>
                                        <option value="8">Check out my Job</option>
                                        <option value="9">Check out my Fan Video</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-xxs-12">
                                    <textarea name="body" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Talk To Us" templates="<div class=&quot;form-group col-xxs-12&quot;></div>" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide content')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" maxlength="5000" required="required"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div id="captcha">
                                    <div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">
                                        <div>
                                            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LejXR0TAAAAAOmd4Ya4FwOMyQar9uGCYU3Qm6P9&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucm9ja3N0YXJnYW1lcy5jb206NDQz&amp;hl=en&amp;v=v1563777128698&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=7eh5s8ewvd10" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-yc8avbksowkq" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe>
                                        </div>
                                        <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="g-response" autocomplete="off">
                                <button class="btn btn-yellow" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                                <!-- ngIf: message -->
                            </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>





<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="press" id="press">Press</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="release" class="press-modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="press-content">
    <div class="press-header">
      <span class="close"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="press-body">
      <h2>Press</h2>
      <p>Have something you want to tell us, ask us or bring to our attention? Feel free to Mouthoff and let us know here. Please bear in mind that we may not be able to answer absolutely everything and we won’t reveal to you any game info that hasn't yet been announced, but we’re always happy to have a look at what you have to say.</p><p>If you have a technical issue that you’d like to report, please <a href="http://www.galaxy-games.co.uk/support" target="_blank">contact our Support Team</a>.</p>
        <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="row common-form pristine valid" action="https://www.galaxy-games.co.uk/mouthoff/mouthoff/submit.json">
                            <div style="display:none;">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" autocomplete="off"></div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-5 col-xxs-12">
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" maxlength="100" placeholder="Name" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide your name')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required="required" id="name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-5 col-xxs-12">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email Address" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide your email address')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required="required" id="email" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xxs-12">
                                    <label for="age">Age</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="age" class="form-control" min="13" max="100" pattern="[0-9]{2}" placeholder="Age" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide your age')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required="required" id="age">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-xxs-12">
                                    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" maxlength="100" placeholder="Subject" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide a subject')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required="required" id="subject">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xxs-12">
                                    <select name="category_id" required="required" id="category-id">
                                        <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                        <option value="1">General Suggestions</option>
                                        <option value="2">GTA Online Suggestions</option>
                                        <option value="3">Crews</option>
                                        <option value="4">Other Social Club Features</option>
                                        <option value="5">Galaxy Warehouse</option>
                                        <option value="6">Customer Support</option>
                                        <option value="7">Other Feedback</option>
                                        <option value="8">Check out my Job</option>
                                        <option value="9">Check out my Fan Video</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-xxs-12">
                                    <textarea name="body" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Talk To Us" templates="<div class=&quot;form-group col-xxs-12&quot;></div>" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide content')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" maxlength="5000" required="required"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div id="captcha">
                                    <div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">
                                        <div>
                                            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LejXR0TAAAAAOmd4Ya4FwOMyQar9uGCYU3Qm6P9&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucm9ja3N0YXJnYW1lcy5jb206NDQz&amp;hl=en&amp;v=v1563777128698&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=7eh5s8ewvd10" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-yc8avbksowkq" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe>
                                        </div>
                                        <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="g-response" autocomplete="off">
                                <button class="btn btn-yellow" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                                <!-- ngIf: message -->
                            </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
button.subscribe{
    background:transparent !important;
    border:none;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    vertical-align:top;
    float:none !important;
    margin-top:7px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
button.subscribe:focus{
    outline:none;
}
/* The Modal (background) */
.subscribe-modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Modal Content */
.subscribe-content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #000;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #ff0000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.subscribe-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}

.subscribe-body {
    padding: 2px 16px;
}
.subscribe-body h2{
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    font-family: DINNext-Bld,sans-serif;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px;
    line-height: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: -.03em;
}
.subscribe-body p{
    margin-left:550px;
    margin-right:550px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    font-family: DINNext-Bld,sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
}
.subscribe-body a.manage{
    margin-right: 1700px;
    padding:6px 20px 3px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:1em;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    vertical-align:top;
    float:none !important;
    color:#000;
    font-family:DINNext-Med,sans-serif;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}
.subscribe-body a.manage:hover{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff
}
.subscribe-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
button.mouthoff{
    background:transparent !important;
    border:none;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    vertical-align:top;
    float:none !important;
    margin-top:7px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
button.mouthoff:focus{
    outline:none;
}
/* The Modal (background) */
.mouthoff-modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Modal Content */
.mouthoff-content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}
.mouthoff-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}
.mouthoff-body {
    padding: 2px 16px;
}
.mouthoff-body h2{
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    font-family: DINNext-Bld,sans-serif;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px;
    line-height: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: -.03em;
}
.mouthoff-body p{
    margin-left:550px;
    margin-right:550px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    font-family: DINNext-Bld,sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
}
.mouthoff-body .row{
    margin-left: 550px;
    margin-right:550px;
}
.mouthoff-body .btn-yellow{
    margin-bottom:100px;
    padding: 9px 20px 6px
}
.mouthoff-body a.manage{
    margin-right: 1700px;
    padding:6px 20px 3px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:1em;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    vertical-align:top;
    float:none !important;
    color:#000;
    font-family:DINNext-Med,sans-serif;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}
.mouthoff-body a.manage:hover{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff
}
.mouthoff-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
button.press{
    background:transparent !important;
    border:none;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    vertical-align:top;
    float:none !important;
    margin-top:7px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
button.press:focus{
    outline:none;
}
/* The Modal (background) */
.press-modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Modal Content */
.press-content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}
.press-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}
.press-body {
    padding: 2px 16px;
}
.press-body h2{
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    font-family: DINNext-Bld,sans-serif;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px;
    line-height: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: -.03em;
}
.press-body p{
    margin-left:550px;
    margin-right:550px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    font-family: DINNext-Bld,sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
}
.press-body .row{
    margin-left: 550px;
    margin-right:550px;
}
.press-body .btn-yellow{
    margin-bottom:100px;
    padding: 9px 20px 6px
}
.press-body a.manage{
    margin-right: 1700px;
    padding:6px 20px 3px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:1em;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    vertical-align:top;
    float:none !important;
    color:#000;
    font-family:DINNext-Med,sans-serif;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}
.press-body a.manage:hover{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff
}
.press-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Javascript

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("subscription");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("subscribe");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// Get the modal
var shoutModal = document.getElementById("shout");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var mouthoffButton = document.getElementById("mouthoff");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spanClose = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
mouthoffButton.onclick = function() {
  shoutModal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
spanClose.onclick = function() {
  shoutModal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal || event.target == shoutModal) {
    shoutModal.style.display = "none";
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
// Get the modal
var releaseModal = document.getElementById("release");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var pressButton = document.getElementById("press");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spanClose = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
pressButton.onclick = function() {
  releaseModal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
spanClose.onclick = function() {
  releaseModal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal || event.target == releaseModal) {
    releaseModal.style.display = "none";
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];` will always get you the first instance of the close button in the dom. In this case it is always the close button for the first modal. Try providing different ids for each of the modal close button and get the references using the `getElementById` method or provide different classes for each close button.

Comment: I did that and now the modals wont even open

Comment: can you provide sample code for what modifications you did??

Comment: Here is a sample https://jsfiddle.net/9mgav8Lw/ and also it is now really only mouth off that won't close